# ssmtp vs. Gmail

Tags: raspberry-pi, ssmtp, gmail

I am trying to setup my raspberry's ssmtp to use my Gmail account. I followed recommendations I found around, everything looks ok but the mail does not come.

ssmtp.conf:

```
root=<my_mail>@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
hostname=<my_account>.ydns.eu
FromLineOverride=YES
AuthUser=<my_mail>@gmail.com
AuthPass=16charpassfromGoogle
UseSTARTTLS=Yes
UseTLS=YES
```

revaliases:

```
root:<my_mail>@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
pi:<my_mail>@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
```

actual command:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo -e  "to: <my_mail>@gmail.com\nsubject: [RASPBERRY]\n\nTest 1...2...3" |  ssmtp -vvv <my_mail>@gmail.com
[<-] 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP z14-20020ac25dee000000b004f4ce9c9338sm415135lfq.283 - gsmtp
[->] EHLO <my_account>.ydns.eu
[<-] 250 SMTPUTF8
[->] STARTTLS
[<-] 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
[->] EHLO <my_account>.ydns.eu
[<-]
ssmtp:  (<my_account>.ydns.eu)
```

I see no error here or in any log (/var/log/mail.*). However, no email arrives. I checked Gmail's spam folder too.

I tried to run the ssmtp with strace. The end looks like this:

```
write(2, "ssmtp:  (<my_account>.ydns.eu)\n", 27ssmtp:  (<my_account>.ydns.eu)
) = 27
gettimeofday({tv_sec=1687337054, tv_usec=642704}, NULL) = 0
getpid()                                = 7587
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = 0
send(4, "<19>Jun 21 11:44:14 sSMTP[7587]:"..., 52, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 52
close(4)                                = 0
getuid32()                              = 1000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
_llseek(4, 0, [0], SEEK_CUR)            = 0
fstat64(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2307, ...}) = 0
read(4, "root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash\n"..., 4096) = 2307
close(4)                                = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, 0xbef3b238)            = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/pi/dead.letter", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666) = 4
_llseek(4, 0, [657], SEEK_END)          = 0
fstat64(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=657, ...}) = 0
write(4, "\n\n", 2)                     = 2
close(4)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

What is it trying to do with /etc/passwd and what should I get from "Inappropriate ioctl for device" message?

What do I miss?

Comment: Is there really no other logged output after the second `EHLO`? The log doesn't actually show it attempting to send an email, only saying "hello" to the server, asking for an encrypted connection and saying "hello" again.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Nothing else appears in the console. I am confused too.

Comment: Where are your log entries?

Comment: @symcbean What entries are you looking for? I have not found anything suspicious in the logs, unfortunately.

Comment: I still wonder why it reads /etc/passwd... After that it write the message to dead.letters. Why?

Comment: @user1608790 the ones which explain what happenend when your MTA connected to Google.

Comment: @symcbean No such found.

Comment: Try Debugging: Add this line to your /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf 
Debug=YES
Now open a second terminal and run:
$ tail -f /var/log/mail.log